# My cat does not get along with my boyfriend's newly introduced dog

Tags: safety, introducing-pets

My boyfriend will be moving in with me. I’ve own a cat for a decade plus now and he is the only pet I’ve owned. I’ve never truly introduced him to a dog but he has seen a few. When I bring my boyfriends dog over he acts he gets very defensive and looks like he wants to seriously hurt her. I have to hold her and even when I do that he will make me feel super uncomfortable and even hiss at me or swipe at me. I separate them two and he will cry outside my door waiting for her. How should I go about this?

Comment: There have been past posts about introducing a cat to a new cat. The same advice applies to introducing a cat to any new animal; the key word is _gradually_. Remember too that cats, at their size, are both predators _and_ prey animals, and have to react defensively if another predator comes into their space. And that dog and cat body language and Sicial interaction are quite different so it takes time for them to learn to at least read each other well enough to know what is and isn't threatening. (Side note: you do know to keep the dog away from the litterbox, right?)